# Can I have the "store relative pathnames to data sources" box checked as the default?

Tags: arcmap

Is there a way to have the "store relative pathnames to data sources" box checked as the default rather than always having to go into the document properties and check the box? ArcMap 10.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in ArcMap 10 you'll want to go to the Customize pulldown--> General Tab--> and under the "General" category, check the last option:

> "Make relative paths the default for new map documents"

Comment: @Tim, great, you'll just want to place a "check" next to the answer to accept it and complete the process.

Comment: Sorry :/ I am a noob! Still learnin.. greatly appreciate your help though!